# Bootstrap installation messed up my menu in SCSS

Tags: bootstrap-4

In my project, I added bootstrap except that now the menu is center. Normally, the menu isn't center, it is on the left, I used SCSS.

I have a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dashboard-template-part-3-g2pkmr?file=src/index.html)

If you remove the bootstrap link, the menu is placed correctly.

*index.html*

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

My problem is that I need to use bootstrap for my new pages... So, I don't know how to keep the menu on the left (SCSS), despite installing bootstrap.

Comment: you need to override the `.container` `max-width` and padding to remove the white space

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk: Thank you, you are right !